# Why MySQL MDL(meta data lock) led to a deadlock?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I'm learning MySQL locks and found some problems with the MDL.

The MySQL verison is 8.0.

There is a table named account using InnoDB.

session 1:

`begin; // start the transaction`

`select * from table account; // acquire the MDL SHARED_READ lock`

session 2:

`alter table account add columnA int; // try to acquire the MDL EXCLUSIVE lock, wait for session 1 to release lock`

Then I try to insert a record to table account in session 1, but **MySQL tells me there is a deadlock and rollback session 1 automatically**.

And I try something different:

session 1:

`begin; // start the transaction`

`insert into account values ('test'); // acquire the MDL SHARED_WRITE lock`

session 2:

`alter table account add columnA int; // try to acquire the MDL EXCLUSIVE lock, wait for session 1 to release lock`

**Then I found it is OK to do the insert and select operations in session 1.**

It really confused me, why I first use the `select` operation to acquire MDL SHARED_READ lock led to a deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are different types of MDL shared locks, SHARED_READ and SHARED_WRITE.

**session 1:**

```
begin; // start the transaction

select * from table account; 
// acquire the MDL SHARED_READ lock
```

We can observe this MDL:

```
mysql> select object_name, lock_type, owner_thread_id from performance_schema.metadata_locks;
+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| object_name    | lock_type    | owner_thread_id |
+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| account        | SHARED_READ  |              64 |
```

**session 2:**

```
alter table account add columnA int; 
// try to acquire the MDL EXCLUSIVE lock, wait for session 1 to release lock

mysql> select object_name, lock_type, owner_thread_id from performance_schema.metadata_locks;
+----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| object_name    | lock_type           | owner_thread_id |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| account        | SHARED_READ         |              64 |
| NULL           | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE |              65 |
| NULL           | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE |              65 |
| NULL           | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE |              65 |
| account        | SHARED_UPGRADABLE   |              65 |
| test/account   | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE |              65 |
| #sql-255_17    | EXCLUSIVE           |              65 |
| account        | EXCLUSIVE           |              65 |
```

**session 1:**

To do an insert, session 1 would have to acquire a new type of MDL lock, but it can't do that while session 2 is queued waiting for a MDL EXCLUSIVE lock.

```
mysql> insert into account () values ();
// try to acquire a MDL SHARED_WRITE lock
// wait for session 2 to release its queued lock request
```

Thus both sessions are waiting for the other, and neither can proceed. This is a deadlock.

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Second experiment:

**session 1:**

```
begin; // start the transaction

select * from table account for update; 
// acquire the MDL SHARED_WRITE lock
```

We can observe this MDL:

```
mysql> select object_name, lock_type, owner_thread_id from performance_schema.metadata_locks;
+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| object_name    | lock_type    | owner_thread_id |
+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| account        | SHARED_WRITE |              64 |
```

This is a different type of MDL. It allows inserts.

**session 2:**

```
alter table account add columnA int; 
// try to acquire the MDL EXCLUSIVE lock, wait for session 1 to release lock
```

Same as previous experiment, the DDL statement waits.

**session 1:**

```
mysql> insert into account () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

There is no additional lock needed. Session 1 already has the MDL SHARED_WRITE lock it needs to do the insert, so it is able to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

And I found if a session has the MDL SHARED_WRITE lock, it can do both insert and select operations.

Here is the additional experiment:

Acquire the MDL SHARED_READ lock first, then acquire the MDL SHARED_WRITE in the same session. Then I found the session holds two locks at that time.

If I reverse the sequence, acquire the MDL SHARED_WRITE lock first, then use the select operation to try to acquire the MDL SHARED_READ lock. The session only holds the MDL SHARED_WRITE lock.

Comment: Yes, because the SHARED_WRITE lock allows the session to do read queries too.